# What should be assumed to justify the multiple timeline in the remedial chaos theory?

Tags: analysis, community

I had this discussion about this episode of *Community* some time ago. I am actually bothered by the fact that since there is a timeline where Abed catch the dice there should not be other timeline. Since there was a canceling action that took place before the completion of the hazardeous mechanism the dice never actually even touched the table. there should only be one timeline : the one where Abed catch the dice.

However, I am feeling like there should be a more formal way to explain this, and also there should be formal ways to explain the coexistence of the seven timeline presented, some meta-physics or philosophical principle may do the trick. (I looked at what determinism said for example but wasn't fully satisfied with what I found)

Can someone bright some light on some timeline theories related to hazard and decision ?

Comment: I don't think this is quite on topic. You are asking for purely real quantum physics theories instead of asking how it worked in the show.

Comment: That said, it's called the many-worlds theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation similar to the superposition that Schrodinger described (as a joke). Essentially, all possible options exist at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely a result of either the **[Many-Worlds Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation)**, or the **[Many-Minds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-minds_interpretation)** (depending on how the universe splitting happens). I won't go too much in details since it isn't the subject (though very interesting), and you'll find plenty on the Internet.

**Quick background**: while the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum physics states that there is a collapse of the Wave function, **Hugh Everett** stated that **all** possible quantum events actually happen in different universes. There isn't only one outcome, but all possible outcomes. The **many-minds interpretation** takes this to a higher level, where the universe splitting would happen at the mind's level. This is a man-centered interpretation and is the one that is most commonly used in animes/series/movies.

**In Community**: You have to think that the few *timelines* (7? I don't remember, haven't watched Community in too long) presented are only a tiny few of the available *timelines* in the multiverse. Every time a choice is made, a new timeline (universe) is created. So there's a timeline where Troy actually never left, and one where Abed catches the dice before it rolls.

I highly recommend you read about the basics of Quantum Theory and then on Everett's interpretation and how it defers from the Copenhagen interpretation. The **Many-worlds interpretation** is a common Sci-fi subject and does have theories to back it up.

Thanks for bringing up Community anyway, always brightens my day.

Comment: Thank you for all the informations! I know quantum theory and everett's interpretation but I wasn't convinced that a quantum event could be happenning here since, strictly speaking, Abed catched the dice before it happenned. the many-minds theory sounds like a good alternative that can explain all of this.

Comment: @JoulinNicolas For Abed's catching the die to have prevented the other timelines, you have to accept that this is the *only* action that creates multiple timelines. But if *every* action creates them, then his catching the die is just one possibility (which subsequently splits off again, of course). The point here is that the *observer* - meaning, the director - chose to shows 6 timelines, five of which split off from the die landing, one of which split off a second earlier.

Comment: It's a very interesting thing to include the director of the show into the process as the observer ! A very meta thought that really fits the show.